# Log Locally and Remotely with rsyslogd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, syslog, rsyslog

How can I make it so log file is stored both remotely and locally using rsyslog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it's as simple as two lines in the config file:

```
*.* @loghost
*.* /var/log/messages
```

The [rsyslog example configs](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_examples.html) have a few instances of teeing like this. The key one:

```
kern.* /var/adm/kernel
kern.crit @finlandia;RFC3164fmt
kern.crit /dev/console
kern.info;kern.!err /var/adm/kernel-info

The second statement directs all kernel messages of the priority crit and 
higher to the remote host finlandia.
[...]
The third rule directs these messages to the actual console, so the person 
who works on the machine will get them, too.
```

Answer (score 5):

Wouter de Bie had a good answer, but he showed the UDP method of sending logs. In order to send them over the more reliable (though not 100%) TCP use something like:

```
\*.* @@remote.server.ip
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the following line in your /etc/rsyslog.d/remote.conf:

```
*.* @remote.server.ip
```

This can easily be extended for only logging specific facilities and levels to the remote server.

Comment: Won't this just send the logs to the remote server and not the local one?

Comment: By default the configuration in Ubuntu for rsyslogd is done in /etc/rsyslog.conf. Here, local logging is already configured. Adding extra files in your /etc/rsyslog.d causes to log to a remote (or local) location as well. The /etc/rsyslog.d directory allows you to extend your configuration (not override it).