# does remote logging stops local logging

Tags: log-files, rsyslog, syslog, graylog

I'm using a Graylog server to centralize logs from network equipment and servers and I'm wondering if the Syslog service on the switches, windows machines, and other equipment, that service still going to save logs locally or just send them remotely and stops the local logging process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless configured to do so. You should be able to configure rsyslog to write both locally and remotely.

Comment: so I need to configure rsyslog to write on both locally and remotely or it will automatically stop writing logs locally, am I getting it right?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/181371/log-locally-and-remotely-with-rsyslogd